# Uniform lower bound in the Landau Prime Ideal Theorem

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Are there positive constants $\alpha,\beta,C$ such that for every number field $K$, the number of prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}_K$ of norm at most $x$ is at least $\alpha x^{\beta}$ for all $x\geq C$?

Crucially, $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $C$ must not depend on $K$ (and neither on $x$).

We can assume the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis if it helps.

Comment: When you say at least $\alpha x^\beta$, do you mean for all sufficiently large $x$? If so, then this isn't bad with GRH --- actually, it follows pretty immediately. But if you want a uniform $\alpha$ to hold for every number field for every $x$, then this might not be true.

Comment: @davidlowryduda: I want the lower bound for all $x\geq C$, where $C$ is an absolute constant (does not depend on $K$). Do you have an idea about how to prove that this is not true?

Comment: @user3533 You should edit the question to include the information from your comment. I suspect that given any $C>0$, there exists a number field $K$ with *no* prime ideals of norm at most $C$. This would be the case, for instance, if $[K:\Bbb Q]=d$ with $2^d>C$, and all the rational primes up to $C$ were inert in $K$.